# Multiple ONs and JOINs

Tags: mysql, join

I learned, that I can rewrite a query like

```
SELECT d
FROM tbl1
WHERE a in (
    SELECT  b
    FROM tbl2
    WHERE c = "Something"
)
```

into the (in my opinion faster) query:

```
SELECT d
FROM tbl1 LEFT JOIN tbl2
ON tbl1.a = tbl2.b
WHERE tbl2.c = "Something"
```

But I have a problem to rewrite following query:

```
SELECT name, nick
FROM cu
WHERE uid IN (
    SELECT friend
    FROM cf
    WHERE user IN (
        SELECT uid
        FROM cu
        WHERE sid = "abc"
    )
)
```

**EDIT**:

Just found it: [Left Join Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/left-join-optimization.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be equivalent:

```
select cu.*
from cu join
     cf
     on cu.uid = cf.friend join
     cu cu2
     on cu2.uid = cf.user
where cu2.sid = 'abc';
```

Note that you only need inner joins for this.

Comment: Just found the solution. Thank you anyway for the fast answer :)

Comment: @Cubinator73 . . . It is useful to look at these two solutions side-by-side to better understand different ways of doing things.  Good luck learning SQL.